# IBM WebSphere AS LDAP login module?

Tags: java, ldap, websphere, websphere-8, jaas

I would like to authenticate users by LDAP credentials in WebSphere AS inside my app. I see that `com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule` is available for authenticating entire user repository including LDAP. So I think that it would be it. But I don't know how to use this login module in code. I don't see any documentation about which options I need to provide in `jaas.conf` and how actually use this in Java code. I know how to use some custom login modules, but I don't know what exact things I need to do in code for that specific module (any special arguments?, callbackhandlers? etc.). WebSphere AS version is 8.5.5.

How to authenticate users in Java code using some LDAP login module in WebSphere AS?

Answer (score 0):

For authentication with LDAP you don't need to use any Login modules, WebSphere supports LDAP out of the box. Just configure application security via web administrative console and configure your LDAP as repository in Federated registry or in standalone LDAP.

See also:

- [Selecting a registry or repository](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_useregistry.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1&lang=en)
- [Configuring a single built-in, file-based repository and one or more Lightweight Directory Access Protocol repositories in a federated repository configuration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twim_ldap_filebased.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1-3-10&lang=en)

Comment: I have a LDAP repository configured in WAS and my question is how can I authenticate users using that LDAP directly in Java code. Let's say I have a servlet with two text fields, username and password. User submits this data to my app and I have to check in Java code if those credentials are correct. My use case is different than that, it is only an example, but the basic thing is authenticating users in java code using login modules. Users sends credentials somehow to my app and I have to check in java code if they are correct .

Comment: I have found a login module which seems to be exactly what I need and its usage is well documented. https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.api.doc/jaas_aix_64/com/ibm/security/auth/module/LdapLoginModule.html

Comment: @ctomek if you want to authenticate in servlet, you should just use `request.login(user,pass)` method from Servlet API. It will automatically create also required SSO token (LTPA). But if you insist on using login modules, that's your choice. :-)